# SQL Server 2000 - Programmatically Limit Access to Database Owner?

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2000, dbo

How would I programmatically go about limiting the access of a database in SQL Server 2000 to the database owner for that database? Example... if I right-click "Properties" on the "Northwind" database in Enterprise Manager, the Owner is listed as `sa`. How would I limit access for this database to just the `sa` login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the database to RESTRICTED_USER availability.

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET RESTRICTED_USER

-- OR --

ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET RESTRICTED_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190249.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa275464(SQL.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts:

- You can neither deny not restrict the sa login at all, anywhere in a SQL Server Instance
- Do not use "sa" day to day
- It makes more sense to limit to the members of the db_owner database role, per database (`SET RESTRICTED_USER` above)
- The database owner id is fairly random: sa only owns this because sa created it, or ownership was changed to sa

Other than that, what is the reasoning behind your request?

Comment: I'm working on an application that will run a series of scripts to modify/upgrade the schema of a given database, and need to allow `sa` access for this program... however, I don't want other users/programs connecting to the database while these schema modifications are being performed. I think the `SET RESTRICTED_USER` answer is what I'm looking for. Thanks for your helpful comments as well, the more I know about the `sa` login the better.

Comment: Ah OK, makes sense. SET RESTRICTED_USER is what you need then.